# How to find "fill=rgb(145, 158, 145) " style with Python web driver

Tags: python, webdriver

I;m trying to catch element with python web driver 
These are 2 attempts in my code

```
CatchText2 = self.SELENIUM_DRIVER.find_element_by_xpath(self.PictureIcon).get_attribute("style")

CatchText2 = self.SELENIUM_DRIVER.find_element_by_xpath(self.PictureIcon).value_of_css_property('fill')
```

`PicturIcon` is the xpath of the element

This is my elemet:

```
<polygon class="st0" ng-show="dc.getData('vm'+dc.getModel()).reception >=0" ng-style="dc.getData('vm'+dc.getModel()).receptionColor" points="83.7,180.1 34.5,216.5 34.5,244.5 83.7,244.5  " style="fill: rgb(145, 158, 145);"></polygon>
```

Any help will be appriciated
Thanks

Comment: What value did your `get_attribute` attempt return?

Comment: After checking it again it seems that my problem is different.It seems that i cannot locate the element at all.Im tring to locate it :

Comment: Like this: CatchText2 = self.SELENIUM_DRIVER.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="j_id0:j_id5:j_id6:j_id36"]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li[1]/div/svg/g/g[1]/path[1]')   and also with switch to frame  :self.SELENIUM_DRIVER.switch_to_frame("itarget")
                CatchText2 = self.SELENIUM_DRIVER.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="j_id0:j_id5:j_id6:j_id36"]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li[1]/div/svg/g/g[1]/path[1]')

Comment: I looked at the html and i have only one frame =itarget and dont understand why i cant locate after witching to this frame

Comment: OK.I have some progress.the reason i cant locate was" unexpted eof while parsing" have no idea why.becaue when i find element by class it works.the problem is that i have 3 classes with same name and i need to find them all.Please help